# Swap multiple uploaded input files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I try to make some file upload function in my web application.

I made it enable to upload up to three files on server, but I still have a swapping files issue when I try to delete files.

First my code looks like following:

request.jsp

HTML side

```
<tr>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">Attachment</td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
    <input type="file" id="docFile1" name="docFile1" size="50" style="width:85px;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test1" class="test1" style="border:0;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <button type="button" id="clearDocFile1" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid hidden solid;">
    <input type="file" id="docFile2" name="docFile2" size="50" style="display:none; width:85px;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test2" class="test2" style="border:0;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <button type="button" id="clearDocFile2" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
    <input type="file" id="docFile3" name="docFile3" size="50" style="display:none; width:85px;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test3" class="test3" style="border:0;"/></td>
    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
    <button type="button" id="clearDocFile3" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>                 
</tr>
```

JavaScript side

```
var docInput = document.getElementById('docFile1');
docInput.addEventListener("change", getDocumentFileInfo1, false);

function getDocumentFileInfo1() {
    var fileList1 = this.files;
    oFReader1 = new FileReader();
    oFReader1.name = fileList1[0].name;
    getGetOne = oFReader1.name;
    oFReader1.size = fileList1[0].size;
    console.log("name outside:", oFReader1.name);
    console.log("size outside:", oFReader1.size);
    $("#fileName1").val(oFReader1.name);
    $('#test1').val(oFReader1.name);
    if (oFReader1 != ""){
        $("#docFile2").show();
        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#docFile1").hide();
    } else {
        $("#docFile2").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile1").hide();
        $("#docFile1").show();
    }; 
};

var docInput2 = document.getElementById('docFile2');
docInput2.addEventListener("change", getDocumentFileInfo2, false);

function getDocumentFileInfo2() {
    var fileList2 = this.files;
    oFReader2 = new FileReader();
    oFReader2.name = fileList2[0].name;
    getGetTwo = oFReader2.name;
    oFReader2.size = fileList2[0].size;
    console.log("name outside:", oFReader2.name);
    console.log("size outside:", oFReader2.size);
    $("#fileName2").val(oFReader2.name);
    $('#test2').val(oFReader2.name);

    if (oFReader2 != ""){
        $("#docFile3").show();
        $("#clearDocFile2").show();
        $("#clearDocFile1").hide();
        $("#docFile2").hide();
    } else if (oFReader2 = undefined) {
        $("#docFile3").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile2").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#docFile1").show();
    };

    if (getGetOne == oFReader2.name) {
        alert("You cannot attach two same files");
        $("#docFile2").val("");
        $("#fileName2").val("");
        $("#test2").val("");
        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#clearDocFile2").hide();
        $("#docFile2").show();
        $("#docFile3").hide();
    };
};

var docInput3 = document.getElementById('docFile3');
docInput3.addEventListener("change", getDocumentFileInfo3, false);

function getDocumentFileInfo3() {
    var fileList3 = this.files;
    oFReader3 = new FileReader();
    oFReader3.name = fileList3[0].name;
    getGetThree = oFReader3.name;
    oFReader3.size = fileList3[0].size;
    console.log("name outside:", oFReader3.name);
    console.log("size outside:", oFReader3.size);
    $("#fileName3").val(oFReader3.name);
    $('#test3').val(oFReader3.name);

    if (oFReader3 != ""){
        $("#clearDocFile1").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile2").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile3").show();
        $("#docFile3").hide();
    } else {
        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#clearDocFile2").show();
        $("#clearDocFile3").hide();
        $("#docFile3").show();
    };

    if (getGetOne == oFReader3.name || getGetTwo == oFReader3.name) {
        alert("You cannot attach two same files");
        $("#docFile3").val("");
        $("#fileName3").val("");
        $("#test3").val("");
        $("#clearDocFile2").show();
        $("#clearDocFile3").hide();
        $("#docFile3").show();
    };
};
```

(SKIP)

```
$('#formAddNewDoc').ajaxForm();
    var options = {
        url:"<c:url value='/app/addDocument/files'/>",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : "application/json",
        beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
        options.context = $form;
    },
    beforeSend: function(e) {
        e.setRequestHeader('token', 'euejrhzkehrkherkhekr');
    },
    complete: function (data){
        var file_name = data.responseText;
        console.log(file_name);

        var jsonTwo = {
            fileName1 : $("#fileName1").val(),
            fileName2 : $("#fileName2").val(),
            fileName3 : $("#fileName3").val(),
            documentId : $("#documentId").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : 'json',
            type : "POST",
            url : "<c:url value='/app/addDocument/fileInfo'/>",
            data : JSON.stringify(jsonTwo),
            success : function(jsonTwo) {
                if (status){
                    toastMessage("Add File Info", "Added File Info Successfully", CONSTANT.TOASTICONSUCCESS, CONSTANT.TOASTBOTTOMCENTERPOS, "");
                } else {
                    toastMessage("Add File Info", "Error Occurred", CONSTANT.TOASTICONERROR, CONSTANT.TOASTBOTTOMCENTERPOS, "");
                }
            },
```

ApprovalController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addDocument/fileInfo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean addDocumentFile(@RequestBody DocumentFile documentFile) {
    try {
        //String primary = autoPrimaryKeyService.autoNumberByTable("document_file", "fileId", AutoPrimaryKey.FILE);
        String anotherOne = autoPrimaryKeyService.autoNumberByTable("document", "documentId", AutoPrimaryKey.APPROVAL);
        //documentFile.setFileId(primary);
        documentFile.setDocumentId(anotherOne);
        documentFileService.addDocumentFile(documentFile);

        logger.info("Added File Successfully");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Added File", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addDocument/files")
@ResponseBody
public DocumentFile handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam(value = "docFile1", required = false) MultipartFile docFile1,
        @RequestParam(value = "docFile2", required = false) MultipartFile docFile2,
        @RequestParam(value = "docFile3", required = false) MultipartFile docFile3) {

    String primary = autoPrimaryKeyService.autoNumberByTable("document", "documentId", AutoPrimaryKey.APPROVAL);
    File file = new File(ViewMapper.UPLOAD_DOC_PATH + "/" + primary);

    String temp1 = ViewMapper.UPLOAD_DOC_PATH + "/" + primary + "/" + docFile1.getOriginalFilename();
    String file_name1 = docFile1.getOriginalFilename();

    DocumentFile fileString = new DocumentFile();

    if (!file.mkdir()){
        file.mkdir();
    }

    if(!docFile1.isEmpty()){
        try {
            byte[] bytes = docFile1.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(temp1)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            fileString.setFileName1(file_name1);

            if(!docFile2.isEmpty()){
                String temp2 = ViewMapper.UPLOAD_DOC_PATH + "/" + primary + "/" + docFile2.getOriginalFilename();
                String file_name2 = docFile2.getOriginalFilename();

                byte[] bytes2 = docFile2.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(temp2)));
                stream2.write(bytes2);
                stream2.close();
                fileString.setFileName2(file_name2);
            }

            if(!docFile3.isEmpty()){
                String temp3 = ViewMapper.UPLOAD_DOC_PATH + "/" + primary + "/" + docFile3.getOriginalFilename();
                String file_name3 = docFile3.getOriginalFilename();

                byte[] bytes3 = docFile3.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream3 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(temp3)));
                stream3.write(bytes3);
                stream3.close();
                fileString.setFileName3(file_name3);
            }

            DocumentFile document = new DocumentFile();
            documentFileService.addDocumentFile(document);

            logger.info("Uploaded File Successfully.");
            return fileString;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Uploaded File.", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("No File.");
        return null;
    }       
}
```

And for now, when you first launch the application, a user would see a screen like following:

[image]

Then if the user choose it will change like these

[image]

[image]

[image]

The user can only delete the last added item, and choose another file when he/she delete it.

I want to make it works like when there are three items, if the second one is deleted, then the third item becomes the second item and the third item becomes empty.

Before, I tried something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(to) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var copy_to = $(to).clone(true);
        var copy_from = $(this).clone(true);
        $(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
        $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
    });
};

$("#clearDocFile2").on('click', function(){
    var temTwo = $("#docFile2").val();
    var ttemTwo = $("#fileName2").val();
    var tttemTwo = $("#test2").val();

    var temThree = $("#docFile3").val();
    var ttemThree = $("#fileName3").val();
    var tttemThree = $("#test3").val();

    if (temThree == ""){
        $("#docFile2").val("");
        $("#fileName2").val("");
        $("#test2").val("");
        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#clearDocFile2").hide();
        $("#clearDocFile3").hide();
        $("#docFile3").hide();
        $("#docFile2").show();
    } else {
        $("#fileName2").swapWith("#fileName3");
        $("#test2").swapWith("#test3");

        $("#clearDocFile1").show();
        $("#clearDocFile2").show();
        $("#clearDocFile3").hide();
        $("#docFile3").show();
        $("#docFile2").hide();
    }
});
```

But when I tried to delete the second item out of three, this only swaps the name (also the name of third item wasn't empty) and selected file was still same, so when I submit the form, both second and third item did not get uploaded.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to swap the values, you should simply remove the whole row, and append a new one.

As ffar as i know, there is no safe way (in terms of, will always work) to do swap values like this on file-inputs, since this would include reading and setting the file-url by code, wich will result in some serious security-problems. Even the filepath will sometimes be obfuscated, non-present due to security concerns in some browsers.

enumerated field-names, variables, whatever are almost every time a bad sign.
I don't have any experience with JSP; for PHP one can name all three fields as `file[]` and PHP would provide me with an Array of values under the name of `file`; don't know wether there is a similar thing in JSP.

On a quick google-search I've found this example http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-multiple-files-upload-example for JSPs that seems to work without any field-names at all; still can't tell how good the code is.

Comment: Are you trying to say I should try something like .closest() of jQuery while modify docFIle1, docFile2, and docFile3 as docFile[]?  In this case, how should I change my controller part if I made their name as same?